# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (30) : unknown error at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:32

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, pytorch

```
using config:

       'CONFIG_NAME': 'stageI',
       'CUDA': True,
       'DATASET_NAME': 'coco',
       'DATA_DIR': '/home/anwar/Documents/StackGAN-Pytorch- 
        master/data/coco',
       'EMBEDDING_TYPE': 'cnn-rnn',
       'GAN': {'CONDITION_DIM': 128, 'DF_DIM': 96, 'GF_DIM': 192, 'R_NUM': 
        4},
       'GPU_ID': '1',
       'IMSIZE': 64,
       'NET_D': '',
       'NET_G': '',
       'STAGE': 1,
       'STAGE1_G': '',
       'TEXT': {'DIMENSION': 1024},
       'TRAIN': {'BATCH_SIZE': 128,
       'COEFF': {'KL': 2.0},
       'DISCRIMINATOR_LR': 0.0002,
       'FLAG': True,
       'GENERATOR_LR': 0.0002,
       'LR_DECAY_EPOCH': 20,
       'MAX_EPOCH': 120,
       'PRETRAINED_EPOCH': 600,
       'PRETRAINED_MODEL': '',
       'SNAPSHOT_INTERVAL': 10},
       'VIS_COUNT': 64,
       'WORKERS': 4,
       'Z_DIM': 100
Load filenames from: /home/anwar/Documents/StackGAN-Pytorch- 
master/data/coco/train/filenames.pickle (82783)
embeddings:  (82783, 5, 1024)
```

> THCudaCheck FAIL file=torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp line=32 error=30 :
>   unknown error Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       algo = GANTrainer(output_dir)   File "/home/anwar/Documents/StackGAN-Pytorch-master/code/trainer.py", line
>   45, in **init**
>       torch.cuda.set_device(self.gpus[0])   File "/home/anwar/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/**init**.py",
>   line 262, in set_device
>       torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
>
> RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (30) : unknown error at
>   torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:32

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have no cudnn.Remeber to install the right Version!
Secondly,the version of CUDA may be different from the one needed by pytorch.
I got the same Error, now it goes right.
Good luck!